# Don't I have the authority to reject any suggested edit?

Tags: support, editing, notifications, suggested-edits

I have come across a situation that when I edit someone's post, it is kept on hold for 'peer review' and after the approval of the author it reflects on the site. But when someone suggests edit to my posts, I don't receive any type of prompt and it automatically gets approval. I have gone through the site for last an hour but haven't found any type of setting that can change this.
So, can anyone please tell why is it happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're unable to force the system to allow you to stop people editing your posts, this is a feature of the StackExchange model, that anyone in the community is free to improve upon posts (once they reach a high enough rep to do so). Generally, its a great system which ensures the quality of questions and answers here.

Usually, edits are for minor things such as spelling, or adding MathJax formatting, and should be preserved, however, I grant that there are some users here who edit excessively (if you search meta there have been several recent discussions on this).

If you are against someones edit, you can re-edit your post, or roll-back the post to its original state. Generally once you do this, the person who edited it should get the idea and not try to change it again (avoiding so-called 'edit wars').

Do be aware though, that if you're choosing to roll back perfectly good edits which leave your question poorly worded/formatted, then people are also quite within their right to vote to close.

Also note that until you have a certain amount of reputation, your edits will be placed into a queue for moderation (this is to prevent new users from trashing the site). Once you have sufficient rep, your edits will be applied instantly.

Comment: Yes, I know that 'anyone in the community is free to improve upon posts'. But from the last paragraph of your answer it is evident that there is some privilege called 'Reject' the suggested edit. I am just asking that, **I don't receive any such prompt whether to approve or reject** and the edited posts gets approval automatically.

Comment: My answer was poorly worded, by reject, I meant, should you choose to roll-back edits. There is no notification when someone edits your post, and this notification cannot be turned on. If you want this feature, you can request it at meta.stackexchange.com, as any change would effect the whole of the stack exchange network (the community moderators here do not have that power).

Comment: Okay. But when I edit someone's post, there is something called 'peer review' flashes and my edit is effectively processed after quite a time. Is in that mean time that edit reviewed by the moderator?

Comment: Until you have a certain amount of reputation, your edits will be placed into a queue for moderation (this is to prevent new users from trashing the site). Once you have sufficient rep, your edits will be applied instantly.

Comment: Yes, Now I have got rid of all my confusions. Thanks for your response @NotEvans.

Comment: @chail10 A suggested edit (from users <2000 rep.) can of course be rejected in the edit queue. It needs two users who have the privilege (or one moderator) to either approve or reject. If the edit is substantial, the OP should get a notification, too, and can either approve or reject. Edits of users with >2000 rep. will instantly be applied and the only way to revert this is another edit or rollback. You can @-notify any editor to tell h{er..im} your concerns. If you are really unhappy with an edit and need an explanation you can bring it here to meta.chemistry.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is approaching the ‘issue’ from the wrong angle and is probably based on a misunderstanding.

The model of Stack Exchange is indeed that anyone can *suggest* an edit. When an edit is suggested, it enters a review queue and it also drops a note in the OP’s inbox. The edit can be approved or rejected by:

- **two** votes for either approve or reject from the review queue
- **the OP** who has the power to flat-out reject or approve an edit.
- (there is a third possibility which I’ll address in a second).

Furthermore, Stack Exchange believes in community moderation, so anybody who has passed a certain community contribution threshold may go to the review queues and vote to accept or reject edits.

Requiring approval for your edits is tiresome. Some people have been around and contributed so well (as measured by their reputation) that Stack Exchange trusts them that their edits won’t be spam, plagiarism, superfluous or anything else that they shouldn’t be. These people’s edits are applied *immediately* i.e. without prior review. [This priviledge is gained by reaching 2000 reputation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

Since Stack Exchange trusts these people to edit well, these are also the people entrusted to the suggested edit review queues, i.e. they also have the power to judge over other people’s edits.

This trust can even be used to single-handedly rule *good* or *bad* — if they decide to further improve the post at the same time. This option is presented by the two review options *accept and improve* and *reject and improve* — in both cases the person with edit priviledges has a clear view of the state of the post, what the edit does and what it does not (although it should be done). These single-handed overriding buttons basically mean ‘if I had found the unedited post, I would put it here’, which may help to explain why they exist.

So to sum this up:

- You get notified of a pending edit suggestion if the suggestion was made by a user *without* the priviledge.

  - The suggestion also enters a review queue where others can decide if the edit was helpful or not.
  - If the review queue is faster than you, you will either not receive any notification (reject) or a notification of a successful edit (accept).
- You get notified of a recent edit if the edit was performed by a user *with* the priviledge.

Neither variant can be configured; both are hard-coded into the system.

Comment: Yes! That was my angle of concern, Thanks for understanding and letting me know the correct way.

Comment: In the case where you edit the post from the queue, Community♦ is technically accepting or rejecting an edit, and as a mod, the vote is binding.